# Restrict block visibility by page and content type in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-blocks

I declared a block to display the 3 most recent articles published and I would like to display it on a specific page so I added
`/my-page/` into the block page list but it didn't worked. I then changed it to `/my-page*` and it worked but I ended up getting my block on `/my-page/other-content` which is not what I wanted.

Moreover if I declare a list of page and a content type, my content type is not taken into account.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you first of all simply try `/my-page` without the trailing slash, please.

Apart from that you may have a look a the following module:

[Block Exclude pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_exclude_pages)

Then you'd say `Show for the listed pages`

```
/my-page*
!/my-page/*
```

---

And regarding the content types there was a bug with ctools which still seems to be unfixed. So you may have a look at:

[Block Visibility Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups)

Here you can configure a visibility group which hides blocks for a specific content type.

The visibility groups also are reusable, that means you can apply the same settings on multiple blocks.

Comment: I tried /my-page, I forgot to mention it, but it doesn't work (which surprised me ...)

Comment: @Tibo – I see. Then try Block Exclude Pages with these rules: `/my-page*` and `!/my-page/*`.

Comment: I will try that. Do you know if it's the expected behaviour that by adding a page in the list, all my selected content types does not show the block anymore ?

Comment: @Tibo – Yes that's intended. You may find a different rule than that matches your needs. Maybe you use the brilliant Pathauto module and give every content type a default URL pattern like `contenttypename/[node:title]` and then add or exclude them by their URL aliases one by one in your block settings. You could also do that programmatically but that's a totally different story.